# jpa with embedded derby db using maven javafx

Tags: maven, jpa, eclipselink

My persistence file content: "jdbc:derby:deliceplaceDB;create=true". But I when execute "mvn clean javafx:run" the database "deliceplaceDB" is not created. Please need help!!!

My persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="deliceplacePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:deliceplaceDB;create=true" />
             <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="sql/create.sql"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I would like to load my sql file "create.sql" at runtime but is not working.
thanks

Comment: What is the point of eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode? Are you looking to have EclipseLink generate tables from the model, or is your script supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified a load script source - which is used for post creation scripts - and specified DDL generation would go to the database, but this only occurs once you turn it on.

specify properties:

```
   <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="sql/create.sql"/>
```

the first tell JPA to create the database when deploying, the second tells it to look for a script, the third where the script is.

See [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/) for a good description of other options, and check and post the logs if there are any problem.

Comment: I am looking eclipse to generate table from script "sql/create".

Comment: I will try your solution. I think it will work